# Multithreading Through a list correct

Tags: java, multithreading

My experience of multi threading is limited, so to be honest this may be a terrible idea. Here's what I want to do:

ArrayList of 50 URLS (example)
Use x amount of threads (5 for example) to access a range of URLs within the list
Call generic method to process URL (retrieve html)
Store result in a master list along with other thread result

Now I'm stuck on processing the ArrayList with multiple threads, my current idea was to divide the list by how many URLS are in the list, and allocate a number range to each thread to process e.g.

Thread 1 - 0-7
Thread 2 - 8-15

etc

I'm assuming this is a terrible method, but I can't really find an example approach.

Help / Advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Downloading multiple html pages concurrently is the end goal of it

Comment: Download [Java Concurrent Animated](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaconcurrenta/), should give you a idea how you can work things out.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a pool of threads where each thread processes a single URL at
   a time from the list.
2. Keep a global index counter so that when a
   thread completes it can retrieve the next URL from the list to process.
3. Do this until all URLs are processed ie. index == list.size()

This way all threads are utilized fully until the job is complete.  You can play around with the number of threads in the pool to optimize performance for your particular runtime environment.

Just make sure your index counter code is thread safe. :)

Comment: And make sure you don't do modification on the list itself, with the threads, at the exact same time. Use a synchronized function, or an existing Concurrent data structure, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A much easier approach is to just use an `ExecutorService` to process URLs on-demand and then retrieve the results using `Future`s:

```
class URLProcessor {

    class ThreadTask implements Callable<String> {
         private String url;

         public ThreadTask(String url) {
             this.url = url;
         }

         public String call() {
             // process url
             // return a String result
         }
    }

...


// input urls
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
// futures to retrieve task results
List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
// results
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
// pool with 5 threads
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5); 

// enqueue tasks
for(String url: urls) {
    futures.add(exec.submit(new ThreadTask(url)));
}

// wait for tasks to finish
for(Future<String> future: futures) {
    results.add(future.get());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, ended up using pretty much this, I owe you :)

Comment: @Ash: Is your problem still not solved? Did you find other issues with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

I'm open to alternatives/criticisms... I'm not an expert of multithreading but in the past I've done something like this:

```
public class MainController {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadGroup workers = new ThreadGroup("workers");
        Iterator<String> urls = getUrlList().iterator();
        while(workers.activeCount() < 5 && urls.hasNext()) {
            UrlProcessor proc = new UrlProcessor(urls.next());
            Thread worker = new Thread(workers, proc);
            worker.start();
        }
    }

    private static List<String> getUrlList() {
        return null;  //To change body of created methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}


public class UrlProcessor implements Runnable {

    private String url;

    public UrlProcessor(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void run() {
        // process URL
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Task for each URL and submit it to an Executor.

The Task could look like this:

```
class UrlTask implements Callable<String>{
    final URL url;

    UrlTask(URL url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String call(){
         return fetch( url );
    }
}
```

and be used like this:

```
Collection<Future<String>> results = new Arraylist<Future<String>>();
for( URL each : urls ){
    UrlTask task = new UrlTask( each);
    Future<String> result = executor.submit( task );
    results.add( result );
}

for( Future<String> result : results ){
    String content = result.get();
    // process content
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A thread pool offers a solution to both the problem of thread life-cycle overhead and the problem of resource thrashing.

You may want to look here for [Thread pools and work queues](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0730/index.html)